# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: Unexpected List modification while multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, concurrency

I'm using multithreading to process a List of Strings in batches, however I'm getting this error when the Runnable task is iterating over the List to process each String.

For example the code roughly follows this structure:

```
public class RunnableTask implements Runnable {

private List<String> batch;

    RunnableTask(List<String> batch){
        this.batch = batch;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        for(String record : batch){

            entry = record.split(",");
            m = regex.matcher(entry[7]);

            if (m.find() && m.group(3) != null){
                currentKey = m.group(3).trim();
                currentValue = Integer.parseInt(entry[4]);

                if ( resultMap.get(currentKey) == null ){
                    resultMap.put(currentKey, currentValue);
                } else {
                    resultMap.put(currentKey, resultMap.get(currentKey) + currentValue);
            }   
        }

    }
} 
}
```

Where the thread that is passing these batches for processing never modifies "batch" and NO CHANGES to batch are made inside the for loop. I understand that this exception ConcurrentModificationException is due to modifying the List during iteration but as far as I can tell that isn't happening. Is there something I'm missing?

Any help is appreciated,

Thankyou!

**UPDATE1:** It seems instance-variables aren't thread safe. I attempted to use CopyOnWriteArrayList in place of the ArrayList but I received inconsistent results - suggesting that the full iteration doesn't complete before the list is modified in some way and not every element is being processed.

**UPDATE2:** Locking on the loop with sychronized and/or a reentrantlock both still give the same exception.

***I need a way to pass Lists to Runnable tasks and iterate over those lists without new threads causing concurrency issues with that list.***

Comment: Given that you don't show the code inside the foreach loop, no one can tell. Also, is your list modified _outside_ of the runnable?

Comment: I will bet a beer that either the caller, or your loop is modifying batch.

Comment: The processing inside the loop only uses record, and makes no reference to batch.

Comment: Use a List iterator instead of directly iterating over the list and modifying it.

Comment: Your UPDATEs are proof that caller, or somebody, is modifying the list.  p.s. try making your instance var batch final.

Comment: The original instantiation of the list is the only place where the list is being modified. It seems that each new task instantiation causes concurrency issues with the batch list. I'm having trouble understanding why this is the case

Comment: You create a new instance of a List each time, right?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that this exception ConcurrentModificationException is due to modifying the List during iteration but as far as I can tell that isn't happening

Ok, consider what happens when you create a new thread, passing a reference to `RunnableTask` instance, initialized with a different list as constructor parameter? You just changed the list reference to point to different list. And consider what happens when at the same time, a different thread inside the `run()` method, is changing the `list`, at any point. This will at some point of time, throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

*Instance Variables are not **Thread-Safe***.

Comment: I had assumed it was thread safe if each new thread is a seperate instance. Could you suggest a modification that would be thread-safe?

Comment: I'm missing something.  His RunnableTask has a reference to the List.  Which isn't changing after construction.  There is no "the list reference", there are n separate references.  As I understand his code.  Note: would be better if batch was declared final.

Comment: @howlerdingdong. You can take a look at [java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: @user949300. You can create multiple threads passing the same reference of `RunnableTask`. Try doing this.

Comment: Assuming that run() doesn't modify batch it should work.  Though this late at night I may be missing something.  My bet is that his loop in run() is indirectly changing something.

Comment: @user949300. Well, yeah. that's of course true. Only when you modify list, at any point inside your `run()` method, not neccessarily in while iterating, this will be an issue. If you no where modify list, then it won't throw that exception.

Comment: I attempted using CopyOnWriteArrayList in place of the ArrayList but my results were incosistent, suggesting that the full iteration didn't finish and some values were not processed.

Comment: Sorry, @howlerdingdong. I'm afraid, I won't be able to help much on this, as I'm not an expert in Concurrency Control. May be someone else can take a look. But, I'll try to search for a solution for this.

Comment: @howlerdingdong. Can you post your complete `run()` method?

Comment: Your CopyOnWrite results are proof that something is modifying your List.

Comment: I've modified the original post to include the contents of run().

I should add that when I was originally processing single Strings instead of batches my results were correct and I had no issues.

Comment: I cannot understand the statement "Instance Variables are not Thread-Safe".  I believe thread-safety has nothing to do with whether it is an instance-var or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
public void run() {
    for(String record : new ArrayList(batch)){
        //do processing with record
    }
}
```

There is a sort of problem with all your threads processing the list (is the list modified during the process?) but is difficult to tell with the code you're providing

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to multiple thread concurrently modifying the the source `List` structure. What I would suggest you should devide the source list to new sublist(according to size) and pass that list to threads.

Say your source `List` have 100 elements. and you are running 5 concurrent thread.

```
int index = 0;
List<TObject> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
for(TObject obj:srcList){
    if(i==(srcList.size()/numberOfthread)){
      RunnableTask task = new RunnableTask(tempList);
      tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    }else 
       tempList.add(obj);
}
```

In this case your original list would not be modified.

Comment: How would changing the batch size affect concurrency in any way?

Comment: no you missd the point, It is creating a new whole new list Object

Answer (score 0):

you need to lock the list before accessing its elements. because List is not thread safe. Try this

```
   public void run() {
     synchronizd(batch){
         for(String record : batch){//do processing with record}
     }
   }
```

Comment: Using synchronized on the for loop still gives me exception because the change to batch is happening when new thread instantiations modify batch at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are getting ConcurrentModificationException because your List is getting modified during iteration. If performance is not a critical issue I suggest use synchronization.
public class RunnableTask implements Runnable {

```
private List<String> batch = new ArrayList<String>();

RunnableTask(List<String> batch){
    this.batch = batch;
}


public void run() {
    synchronized (batch) {
        for(String record : batch){//do processing with record}
        }
    }

}
}
```

or even better use [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

Comment: Performance is an issue unfortunately, I'm processing batches in the hundreds of thousands.

Comment: Then use ReentrantLock. It does not lock while reading(what you are apparently doing in processing) it does a volatile read.It will only lock for write.

Comment: Both reentrantlock and synchronized actually still give me the same exception, given again that the modification isn't occurring from the for loop but from the reinstantiation of batch with every new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your followups indicate that you are trying to reuse the same List multiple times.  Your caller must create a new List for each Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously someone else is changing the content of the list, which is out of picture of the code you mentioned.  (***If you are sure that the ConcurrentModificationException is complaining for the `batch` list, but not `resultMap`, and you are actually showing all code in RunnableTask***)

Try to search in your code, for places that is updating the content of the list, check if it is possible concurrently with your `RunnableTask`.

Simply synchronizing in the RunnableTask is not going to help, you need to synchronize all access to the list, which is obviously happening somewhere else.

If performance is an issue to you so that you cannot synchronize on the `batch` list (which prohibit multiple `RunnableTask` to execute concurrently), consider making use of ReaderWriterLock: RunnableTask acquires read lock, while the list update logic acquire the write lock.